# User of autotools-generated tarball gets error message: aclocal-1.13: command not found

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake, m4, autoreconf

I am distributing a tarball with installation scripts generated by autoconf version 2.69. Works fine on many different machines. Now a user, working on a fresh Arch Linux system, reports that `configure` executes properly, but `make` immediately terminates with the following error message:

```
/home/user/project/build-aux/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.13: command not found
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.13' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

There is no `acinclude.m4` in the project directory. The user assures that he has not modified `aclocal.m4`, `configure.ac`, files in `m4/`, or anything else in the project.

The error message makes no sense for me: as I understand, `aclocal` is executed when I run `autoreconf -if`; it generates a file `aclocal.m4` that is part of the tarball I distribute; there is no reason why a user's `make` command should request `aclocal`.

The user further reports that he can solve the problem for himself by running `aclocal`. However, that is not a clean solution: packagers are not supposed to request their users to have autotools installed, right?

For completeness, I attach the full `configure.ac`: is there anything wrong?

```
################################################################################
##  FRIDA: fast reliable interactive data analysis                            ##
##  configure.ac: used by 'autoreconf -i' to prepare for 'configure'          ##
##  (C) Joachim Wuttke, Sebastian Busch 2008-                                 ##
##  http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/frida                                      ##
################################################################################

################################################################################
##  Generic initialization                                                    ##
################################################################################

AC_INIT([frida],[post-2.1.8c],[j.wuttke@fz-juelich.de])
#                ^^^^^ delete "post-" for public releases
# project name must be "frida"; this determines the installation directories

AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign]) # don't insert GNU blala files

################################################################################
##  Select compiler and preprocessors                                         ##
################################################################################

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG(C++)
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 # provided in directory m4
AC_SUBST(AM_CXXFLAGS,"-g -pedantic -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-result -Werror")
# for valgrind --leak-check=full frida, use -O0 -fno-inline

# source files that use -D settings must #include "../config.h"
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h]) # also needed to prevent endless -D option lists

AC_PROG_LEX   # LEX,LEXLIB = "flex","-lfl" or "lex","-ll"
if test "$LEX" = :; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find lex. Aborting.])
fi
AC_PROG_YACC  # YACC = "bison -y" or "byacc" or "yacc"
if test "$YACC" = "yacc"; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find yacc. Aborting.])
fi

## I put this one here only because qmake does: Make sure off_t is 64-bit in *nix, taken from http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:wlNJ8Qe4dBgJ:www.sfr-fresh.com/unix/privat/libfb-v0.18.4b-src.zip:a/src/rtlib/configure.ac+configure.ac+file+offset+bits&hl=de&ct=clnk&cd=5&gl=de&client=firefox-a
AC_DEFINE([_FILE_OFFSET_BITS],64,[File offset bits])

################################################################################
##  Check for headers, defs needed at compile time                            ##
################################################################################

# Consistency check: is source code present?
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/frida2.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([man/frida.pod])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics
AC_C_CONST
AC_C_INLINE
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
AC_STRUCT_TM
AC_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_HEADER_STDC

# Checks for standard includes
AC_FUNC_ALLOCA
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_REALLOC
AC_FUNC_MKTIME
AC_FUNC_STRFTIME

AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gettimeofday],,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find gettimeofday.]))
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memset],      ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find memset.]))
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([mkfifo],      ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find mkfifo.]))
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strchr],      ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find strchr.]))

AC_CHECK_HEADERS([fcntl.h],        ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find fcntl.h.]))
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([math.h],         ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find math.h.]))

# The following headers are needed for code produced by lexx and yacc
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([inttypes.h],     ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find inttypes.h.]))
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([libintl.h],      ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find libintl.h.]))
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([malloc.h],       ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find malloc.h.]))
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([unistd.h],       ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find unistd.h.]))
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stddef.h],       ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find stddef.h.]))

# Non-standard includes
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([gsl/gsl_rng.h gsl/gsl_randist.h gsl/gsl_math.h \
                  gsl/gsl_errno.h gsl/gsl_integration.h gsl/gsl_roots.h \
                  gsl/gsl_sf.h gsl/gsl_sf_debye.h],,
                 AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find required gsl headers.]))

# C includes of our own
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([kww.h],,  AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find kww.h.]))
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([cerf.h],, AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find cerf.h.]))

# C++ includes of our own
AC_TRY_CPP([#include<boost/format.hpp>],,
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find boost/format.hpp.]))
AC_TRY_CPP([#include<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>],,
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find boost/shared_ptr.hpp.]))

AC_TRY_CPP([#include<trivia/file_ops.hpp>],,
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find trivia/file_ops.hpp.]))
AC_TRY_CPP([#include<readplus/readln.hpp>],,
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find readplus/readln.hpp.]))
AC_TRY_CPP([#include<yamlfreeze/yaml.hpp>],,
        AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find yamlfreeze/yaml.hpp.]))

################################################################################
##  Check for libraries, needed at link time                                  ##
################################################################################

# From standard packages
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([cos], [m],, [AC_MSG_ERROR(libm not found or corrupted)])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([cblas_dgemm], [gslcblas],,
             [AC_MSG_ERROR(libgslcblas not found or out of sync)])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([gsl_blas_dgemm], [gsl],,
            [AC_MSG_ERROR(libgsl not found or out of sync)])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([fftw_plan_r2r_1d], [fftw3],,
              [AC_MSG_ERROR(libfftw not found or out of sync)])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([rl_completion_matches], [readline],,
             [AC_MSG_ERROR(libreadline not found or corrupted)])

# From our own C packages
AC_CHECK_LIB([lmfit], [lmmin], ,
              [AC_MSG_ERROR(liblmfit not found or out of sync)])
AC_CHECK_LIB([kww], [kwwp], ,
            [AC_MSG_ERROR(libkww not found or out of sync)])
AC_CHECK_LIB([cerf], [voigt], ,
            [AC_MSG_ERROR(libcerf not found or out of sync)])

# From our own C++ packages (why checking for main? how else?)
AC_CHECK_LIB([trivia], [main], ,
                       [AC_MSG_ERROR(libtrivia not found or out of sync)])
AC_CHECK_LIB([readplus], [main],,
                 [AC_MSG_ERROR(library readplus not found)])
AC_CHECK_LIB([yamlfreeze], [main],,
                 [AC_MSG_ERROR(library yamlfreeze not found)])

################################################################################
##  Check for facilities needed at run time                                   ##
################################################################################

AC_CHECK_PROGS([GNUPLOT], [gnuplot], [:])
if test "$GNUPLOT" = :; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot find gnuplot. Aborting.])
fi

################################################################################
##  make Makefiles                                                            ##
################################################################################

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile man/Makefile share/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Could the problem be due to the presence of files that do not belong in a tarball? Here the contents of the tgz archive, except for the source files themselves:

```
frida2.1.8c/aclocal.m4
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/depcomp
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/ylwrap
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/ltmain.sh
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/missing
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/install-sh
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/config.guess
frida2.1.8c/build-aux/config.sub
frida2.1.8c/CHANGELOG
frida2.1.8c/config.h.in
frida2.1.8c/configure
frida2.1.8c/configure.ac
frida2.1.8c/COPYING
frida2.1.8c/INSTALL
frida2.1.8c/m4/
frida2.1.8c/m4/libtool.m4
frida2.1.8c/m4/m4_ax_boost_regex.m4
frida2.1.8c/m4/ltversion.m4
frida2.1.8c/m4/ltoptions.m4
frida2.1.8c/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
frida2.1.8c/m4/m4_ax_boost_base.m4
frida2.1.8c/m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4
frida2.1.8c/m4/ltsugar.m4
frida2.1.8c/Makefile.am
frida2.1.8c/Makefile.in
frida2.1.8c/man/
...
frida2.1.8c/share/
...
frida2.1.8c/src/
...
frida2.1.8c/test/
...
```

Comment: The issue seems related with obscure "rebuild rules" (http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Rebuilding), and with the "missing" script, with possible workaround in form of a deprecated macro `AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` (http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/maintainer_002dmode.html)

Comment: Did you create the tarball with `make distcheck`?  That usually catches errors such as this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make -d gave a clue:

```
 Considering target file `aclocal.m4'.
   Pruning file `m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4'.
   Pruning file `configure.ac'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `aclocal.m4'.
  Prerequisite `m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4' is older than target `aclocal.m4'.
  Prerequisite `configure.ac' is newer than target `aclocal.m4'.
 Must remake target `aclocal.m4'.
```

Somehow the timestamps got confused, which activated the "rebuild rules". Since this happens again and again, I finally opted for

```
 AM_MAINTAINER_MODE([disable])
```

in `configure.ac`. I read that the author of this macro got convinced it was a bad idea, but for me it seems to work fine. Clear separation of tasks: The maintainer has to run `autoreconf` whenever `configure.ac` or a `Makefile.am` has changed. The end user should neither need nor be induced to regenerate `configure`.

Comment: How is `configure.ac` newer than `aclocal.m4`?  In the tarball you had for it, it was definitely _older_.  You _should_ be distributing `configure.ac`, BTW.

Comment: I often rebuild various projects with modified autotools configuration. They definitely distribute configure.ac to allow that.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis, this led me to a more simpler solution "touch aclocal.mk4"

Answer (score 26):

Ok, so I had this exact problem too, it was driving me nuts. The issue seems to be that I was doing an svn export of the source code to make my src tarball.

Now that is fine, but correct me if I am wrong, but I think svn only commits files that have been modified, not touched. This means that when you come to check out the files using an svn export the files can be chronologically in the wrong order, even though files like:

configure.ac aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.am Makefile.in

Have all been touched recently, svn's date stamps wont be updated; so when you come to release the source package, the dates are in the wrong order and the configure stage will fail (not too obviously).

After doing svn export, remember always to touch these files before the src is bundled into a tar.gz using the commands:

```
svn export <repo address>
cd <repo name>    
touch configure.ac aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.am Makefile.in
```

Otherwise, the user will be forced to either touch the files themselves:

```
touch configure.ac aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.am Makefile.in
./configure
make
```

or run:

```
autoreconf
./configure
automake
make
```

which will retouch these files, instead of just:

```
./configure
make
```

Which is much easier for the end user.

Comment: I think also `m4/*` and possibly `config.h.in` (if using `autoheader`) should be added to the list of `touch`ed files.

Comment: PS `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` is not deprecated, though I can't see how it's related to this problem anyway...

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, i have amended my answer and removed the bit about AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE.

Comment: Same problem occurs using `git`.  Thanks for the insight here.

Answer (score 10):

Running 
`autoreconf -vfi` 
in the directory where the configure file is located (in my case: /source/evtest/evtest-1.31/) worked for me for a missing aclocal-1.13 due to a too new version (aclocal-1.14).

Answer (score 2):

To resolve, run aclocal, then automake in the top level directory before calling make. This will rebuild the makefiles using the installed version of autotools.

Answer (score 1):

Before the actual build, do

```
touch aclocal.mk
```

This will not help in all cases for building software but it sure helps in Jenkins jobs and Rpm build scripts.

Background: in the last `autoreconf` run the tool has discovered that an add-on macro was updated, so it copied ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4 from /usr/share/aclocal/ to ./m4. It did also rebuild the ./aclocal.m4 however that did not introduce a real change. So on the next commit only the ./m4/xxmacro.m4 macro is being sent to the central repository, and on the next versioncontrol-update in a different location you end up with a newer (updated) .m4/xxmacro.m4 than ./aclocal.m4 (not updated). This may even get packaged into a tarball. As Joachim Wuttke has pointed out above, the differences in timestamps triggers the rebuild. And you can avoid the different timestamps by touching aclocal.m4 which defeats the bad assumptions from automake.

Answer (score 0):

I had to recompile exact version to fix the problem. I it was ruining my custom nginx compilation. You can see the fix [here](https://github.com/gp187/nginx-builder/blob/master/fix/aclocal.sh)
or here's the script itself. 1.5 exactly was very important for OpenSSL and Lua compilation

```
#!/bin/bash


# run as root only
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo -e "\e[1;39m[   \e[31mError\e[39m   ] need root access to run this script\e[0;39m"
    exit 1
fi

function install_automake() {
    [ $# -eq 0 ] && { run_error "Usage: install_automake <version>"; exit; }
    local VERSION=${1}
    wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz &> /dev/null
    if [ -f "automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz" ]; then
            tar -xzf automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz
            cd automake-${VERSION}/
            ./configure
            make && make install
            echo -e "\e[1;39m[   \e[1;32mOK\e[39m   ] automake-${VERSION} installed\e[0;39m"

        else
            echo -e "\e[1;39m[   \e[31mError\e[39m   ] cannot fetch file from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/ \e[0;39m"
            exit 1
    fi
}
install_automake 1.15
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue

```
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.14' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

For me this issue was due to same source file I was using same source file to install on another server.
Once I have deleted the old one and extracted the tar file once again on another server the issue got resolved.
I was able to install the Htop command from command line.
PFB for your refrence....

```
[root@client samba_share]# ls
htop-2.0.2  htop-2.0.2.tar.gz
[root@client samba_share]# rm htop-2.0.2
rm: cannot remove `htop-2.0.2': Is a directory
[root@client samba_share]# rm -rf  htop-2.0.2
[root@client samba_share]# ls
htop-2.0.2.tar.gz
[root@client samba_share]# tar -xvf htop-2.0.2.tar.gz

[root@client samba_share]# cd htop-2.0.2
[root@client htop-2.0.2]# ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o fil`enter code here`e.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library `paths` into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... no
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ceil in -lm... yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking whether closedir returns void... no
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for memmove... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking whether gcc -std=c99 option works... yes
checking if compiler supports -Wextra... yes
checking for addnwstr in -lncursesw... yes
checking ncursesw/curses.h usability... yes
checking ncursesw/curses.h presence... yes
checking for ncursesw/curses.h... yes
checking for usable sched_setaffinity... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating htop.1
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
[root@client htop-2.0.2]# make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/samba_share/htop-2.0.2'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-AvailableMetersPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o `test -f 'AvailableMetersPanel.c' || echo './'`AvailableMetersPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-AvailableMetersPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-AvailableMetersPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-CategoriesPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-CategoriesPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-CategoriesPanel.o `test -f 'CategoriesPanel.c' || echo './'`CategoriesPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-CategoriesPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-CategoriesPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-CheckItem.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-CheckItem.Tpo -c -o htop-CheckItem.o `test -f 'CheckItem.c' || echo './'`CheckItem.c
mv -f .deps/htop-CheckItem.Tpo .deps/htop-CheckItem.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-ClockMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-ClockMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-ClockMeter.o `test -f 'ClockMeter.c' || echo './'`ClockMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-ClockMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-ClockMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-ColorsPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-ColorsPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-ColorsPanel.o `test -f 'ColorsPanel.c' || echo './'`ColorsPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-ColorsPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-ColorsPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-ColumnsPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-ColumnsPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-ColumnsPanel.o `test -f 'ColumnsPanel.c' || echo './'`ColumnsPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-ColumnsPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-ColumnsPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-CPUMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-CPUMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-CPUMeter.o `test -f 'CPUMeter.c' || echo './'`CPUMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-CPUMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-CPUMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-CRT.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-CRT.Tpo -c -o htop-CRT.o `test -f 'CRT.c' || echo './'`CRT.c
mv -f .deps/htop-CRT.Tpo .deps/htop-CRT.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-MainPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-MainPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-MainPanel.o `test -f 'MainPanel.c' || echo './'`MainPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-MainPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-MainPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-DisplayOptionsPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-DisplayOptionsPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-DisplayOptionsPanel.o `test -f 'DisplayOptionsPanel.c' || echo './'`DisplayOptionsPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-DisplayOptionsPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-DisplayOptionsPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-FunctionBar.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-FunctionBar.Tpo -c -o htop-FunctionBar.o `test -f 'FunctionBar.c' || echo './'`FunctionBar.c
mv -f .deps/htop-FunctionBar.Tpo .deps/htop-FunctionBar.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Hashtable.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Hashtable.Tpo -c -o htop-Hashtable.o `test -f 'Hashtable.c' || echo './'`Hashtable.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Hashtable.Tpo .deps/htop-Hashtable.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Header.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Header.Tpo -c -o htop-Header.o `test -f 'Header.c' || echo './'`Header.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Header.Tpo .deps/htop-Header.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-htop.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-htop.Tpo -c -o htop-htop.o `test -f 'htop.c' || echo './'`htop.c
mv -f .deps/htop-htop.Tpo .deps/htop-htop.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-ListItem.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-ListItem.Tpo -c -o htop-ListItem.o `test -f 'ListItem.c' || echo './'`ListItem.c
mv -f .deps/htop-ListItem.Tpo .deps/htop-ListItem.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-LoadAverageMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-LoadAverageMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-LoadAverageMeter.o `test -f 'LoadAverageMeter.c' || echo './'`LoadAverageMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-LoadAverageMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-LoadAverageMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-MemoryMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-MemoryMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-MemoryMeter.o `test -f 'MemoryMeter.c' || echo './'`MemoryMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-MemoryMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-MemoryMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Meter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Meter.Tpo -c -o htop-Meter.o `test -f 'Meter.c' || echo './'`Meter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Meter.Tpo .deps/htop-Meter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-MetersPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-MetersPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-MetersPanel.o `test -f 'MetersPanel.c' || echo './'`MetersPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-MetersPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-MetersPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Object.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Object.Tpo -c -o htop-Object.o `test -f 'Object.c' || echo './'`Object.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Object.Tpo .deps/htop-Object.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Panel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Panel.Tpo -c -o htop-Panel.o `test -f 'Panel.c' || echo './'`Panel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Panel.Tpo .deps/htop-Panel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-BatteryMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-BatteryMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-BatteryMeter.o `test -f 'BatteryMeter.c' || echo './'`BatteryMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-BatteryMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-BatteryMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Process.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Process.Tpo -c -o htop-Process.o `test -f 'Process.c' || echo './'`Process.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Process.Tpo .deps/htop-Process.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-ProcessList.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-ProcessList.Tpo -c -o htop-ProcessList.o `test -f 'ProcessList.c' || echo './'`ProcessList.c
mv -f .deps/htop-ProcessList.Tpo .deps/htop-ProcessList.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-RichString.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-RichString.Tpo -c -o htop-RichString.o `test -f 'RichString.c' || echo './'`RichString.c
mv -f .deps/htop-RichString.Tpo .deps/htop-RichString.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-ScreenManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-ScreenManager.Tpo -c -o htop-ScreenManager.o `test -f 'ScreenManager.c' || echo './'`ScreenManager.c
mv -f .deps/htop-ScreenManager.Tpo .deps/htop-ScreenManager.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Settings.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Settings.Tpo -c -o htop-Settings.o `test -f 'Settings.c' || echo './'`Settings.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Settings.Tpo .deps/htop-Settings.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-SignalsPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-SignalsPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-SignalsPanel.o `test -f 'SignalsPanel.c' || echo './'`SignalsPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-SignalsPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-SignalsPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-StringUtils.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-StringUtils.Tpo -c -o htop-StringUtils.o `test -f 'StringUtils.c' || echo './'`StringUtils.c
mv -f .deps/htop-StringUtils.Tpo .deps/htop-StringUtils.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-SwapMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-SwapMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-SwapMeter.o `test -f 'SwapMeter.c' || echo './'`SwapMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-SwapMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-SwapMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-TasksMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-TasksMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-TasksMeter.o `test -f 'TasksMeter.c' || echo './'`TasksMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-TasksMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-TasksMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-UptimeMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-UptimeMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-UptimeMeter.o `test -f 'UptimeMeter.c' || echo './'`UptimeMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-UptimeMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-UptimeMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-TraceScreen.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-TraceScreen.Tpo -c -o htop-TraceScreen.o `test -f 'TraceScreen.c' || echo './'`TraceScreen.c
mv -f .deps/htop-TraceScreen.Tpo .deps/htop-TraceScreen.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-UsersTable.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-UsersTable.Tpo -c -o htop-UsersTable.o `test -f 'UsersTable.c' || echo './'`UsersTable.c
mv -f .deps/htop-UsersTable.Tpo .deps/htop-UsersTable.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Vector.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Vector.Tpo -c -o htop-Vector.o `test -f 'Vector.c' || echo './'`Vector.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Vector.Tpo .deps/htop-Vector.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-AvailableColumnsPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-AvailableColumnsPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-AvailableColumnsPanel.o `test -f 'AvailableColumnsPanel.c' || echo './'`AvailableColumnsPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-AvailableColumnsPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-AvailableColumnsPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-AffinityPanel.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-AffinityPanel.Tpo -c -o htop-AffinityPanel.o `test -f 'AffinityPanel.c' || echo './'`AffinityPanel.c
mv -f .deps/htop-AffinityPanel.Tpo .deps/htop-AffinityPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-HostnameMeter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-HostnameMeter.Tpo -c -o htop-HostnameMeter.o `test -f 'HostnameMeter.c' || echo './'`HostnameMeter.c
mv -f .deps/htop-HostnameMeter.Tpo .deps/htop-HostnameMeter.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-OpenFilesScreen.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-OpenFilesScreen.Tpo -c -o htop-OpenFilesScreen.o `test -f 'OpenFilesScreen.c' || echo './'`OpenFilesScreen.c
mv -f .deps/htop-OpenFilesScreen.Tpo .deps/htop-OpenFilesScreen.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Affinity.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Affinity.Tpo -c -o htop-Affinity.o `test -f 'Affinity.c' || echo './'`Affinity.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Affinity.Tpo .deps/htop-Affinity.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-IncSet.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-IncSet.Tpo -c -o htop-IncSet.o `test -f 'IncSet.c' || echo './'`IncSet.c
mv -f .deps/htop-IncSet.Tpo .deps/htop-IncSet.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-Action.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-Action.Tpo -c -o htop-Action.o `test -f 'Action.c' || echo './'`Action.c
mv -f .deps/htop-Action.Tpo .deps/htop-Action.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-EnvScreen.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-EnvScreen.Tpo -c -o htop-EnvScreen.o `test -f 'EnvScreen.c' || echo './'`EnvScreen.c
mv -f .deps/htop-EnvScreen.Tpo .deps/htop-EnvScreen.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-InfoScreen.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-InfoScreen.Tpo -c -o htop-InfoScreen.o `test -f 'InfoScreen.c' || echo './'`InfoScreen.c
mv -f .deps/htop-InfoScreen.Tpo .deps/htop-InfoScreen.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT htop-XAlloc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htop-XAlloc.Tpo -c -o htop-XAlloc.o `test -f 'XAlloc.c' || echo './'`XAlloc.c
mv -f .deps/htop-XAlloc.Tpo .deps/htop-XAlloc.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT linux/htop-Platform.o -MD -MP -MF linux/.deps/htop-Platform.Tpo -c -o linux/htop-Platform.o `test -f 'linux/Platform.c' || echo './'`linux/Platform.c
mv -f linux/.deps/htop-Platform.Tpo linux/.deps/htop-Platform.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT linux/htop-IOPriorityPanel.o -MD -MP -MF linux/.deps/htop-IOPriorityPanel.Tpo -c -o linux/htop-IOPriorityPanel.o `test -f 'linux/IOPriorityPanel.c' || echo './'`linux/IOPriorityPanel.c
mv -f linux/.deps/htop-IOPriorityPanel.Tpo linux/.deps/htop-IOPriorityPanel.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT linux/htop-IOPriority.o -MD -MP -MF linux/.deps/htop-IOPriority.Tpo -c -o linux/htop-IOPriority.o `test -f 'linux/IOPriority.c' || echo './'`linux/IOPriority.c
mv -f linux/.deps/htop-IOPriority.Tpo linux/.deps/htop-IOPriority.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT linux/htop-LinuxProcess.o -MD -MP -MF linux/.deps/htop-LinuxProcess.Tpo -c -o linux/htop-LinuxProcess.o `test -f 'linux/LinuxProcess.c' || echo './'`linux/LinuxProcess.c
mv -f linux/.deps/htop-LinuxProcess.Tpo linux/.deps/htop-LinuxProcess.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT linux/htop-LinuxProcessList.o -MD -MP -MF linux/.deps/htop-LinuxProcessList.Tpo -c -o linux/htop-LinuxProcessList.o `test -f 'linux/LinuxProcessList.c' || echo './'`linux/LinuxProcessList.c
mv -f linux/.deps/htop-LinuxProcessList.Tpo linux/.deps/htop-LinuxProcessList.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT linux/htop-LinuxCRT.o -MD -MP -MF linux/.deps/htop-LinuxCRT.Tpo -c -o linux/htop-LinuxCRT.o `test -f 'linux/LinuxCRT.c' || echo './'`linux/LinuxCRT.c
mv -f linux/.deps/htop-LinuxCRT.Tpo linux/.deps/htop-LinuxCRT.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2 -MT linux/htop-Battery.o -MD -MP -MF linux/.deps/htop-Battery.Tpo -c -o linux/htop-Battery.o `test -f 'linux/Battery.c' || echo './'`linux/Battery.c
mv -f linux/.deps/htop-Battery.Tpo linux/.deps/htop-Battery.Po
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I"./linux" -rdynamic  -g -O2   -o htop   htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o htop-CategoriesPanel.o htop-CheckItem.o htop-ClockMeter.o htop-ColorsPanel.o htop-ColumnsPanel.o htop-CPUMeter.o htop-CRT.o htop-MainPanel.o htop-DisplayOptionsPanel.o htop-FunctionBar.o htop-Hashtable.o htop-Header.o htop-htop.o htop-ListItem.o htop-LoadAverageMeter.o htop-MemoryMeter.o htop-Meter.o htop-MetersPanel.o htop-Object.o htop-Panel.o htop-BatteryMeter.o htop-Process.o htop-ProcessList.o htop-RichString.o htop-ScreenManager.o htop-Settings.o htop-SignalsPanel.o htop-StringUtils.o htop-SwapMeter.o htop-TasksMeter.o htop-UptimeMeter.o htop-TraceScreen.o htop-UsersTable.o htop-Vector.o htop-AvailableColumnsPanel.o htop-AffinityPanel.o htop-HostnameMeter.o htop-OpenFilesScreen.o htop-Affinity.o htop-IncSet.o htop-Action.o htop-EnvScreen.o htop-InfoScreen.o htop-XAlloc.o linux/htop-Platform.o linux/htop-IOPriorityPanel.o linux/htop-IOPriority.o linux/htop-LinuxProcess.o linux/htop-LinuxProcessList.o linux/htop-LinuxCRT.o linux/htop-Battery.o  -lncursesw -lm
libtool: link: gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -I./linux -rdynamic -g -O2 -o htop htop-AvailableMetersPanel.o htop-CategoriesPanel.o htop-CheckItem.o htop-ClockMeter.o htop-ColorsPanel.o htop-ColumnsPanel.o htop-CPUMeter.o htop-CRT.o htop-MainPanel.o htop-DisplayOptionsPanel.o htop-FunctionBar.o htop-Hashtable.o htop-Header.o htop-htop.o htop-ListItem.o htop-LoadAverageMeter.o htop-MemoryMeter.o htop-Meter.o htop-MetersPanel.o htop-Object.o htop-Panel.o htop-BatteryMeter.o htop-Process.o htop-ProcessList.o htop-RichString.o htop-ScreenManager.o htop-Settings.o htop-SignalsPanel.o htop-StringUtils.o htop-SwapMeter.o htop-TasksMeter.o htop-UptimeMeter.o htop-TraceScreen.o htop-UsersTable.o htop-Vector.o htop-AvailableColumnsPanel.o htop-AffinityPanel.o htop-HostnameMeter.o htop-OpenFilesScreen.o htop-Affinity.o htop-IncSet.o htop-Action.o htop-EnvScreen.o htop-InfoScreen.o htop-XAlloc.o linux/htop-Platform.o linux/htop-IOPriorityPanel.o linux/htop-IOPriority.o linux/htop-LinuxProcess.o linux/htop-LinuxProcessList.o linux/htop-LinuxCRT.o linux/htop-Battery.o  -lncursesw -lm
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/samba_share/htop-2.0.2'
[root@client htop-2.0.2]# make install
make  install-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/samba_share/htop-2.0.2'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/samba_share/htop-2.0.2'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c htop '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c htop /usr/local/bin/htop
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/applications'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 htop.desktop '/usr/local/share/applications'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 htop.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/pixmaps'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 htop.png '/usr/local/share/pixmaps'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/samba_share/htop-2.0.2'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/samba_share/htop-2.0.2'
[root@client htop-2.0.2]# htop
```